# New Project Create Problem After Android SDK Update

Tags: android

All of my existing projects are fine but, starting new projects has problems...

It appears the Main java file has the problem and the hover say's

> "Java Type Language Cannot Be
>   Resolved, It is Indirectly Referenced
>   From Required .class files"

I created the new Projects just like I created the previous 50 projects (before updating the SDK).

Very frustrating (other bugs in the new release, too)...

I deleted the new projects and Imported them as suggested in other posts but, it didn't help.

I noticed the Main Layout (in graphic mode) say's,

> "The project target is not set"

I don't know what that means given that the layout is within the project folder.  The Build target is set to android 1.6

Also (this may be the issue) I get a message panel when finishing the project creation that say's the android

> sdk/tools/lib/proguard.cfg(No such
>   files or Directory)

Which, is true, there isn't one and that was a new addition to the sdk...

Any suggestion...?  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I got this problem, and my solution is to set the target to other API level in project->properties->android, then set it back.

I think this will refresh the .classpath or some other files, not sure, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

It is annoying indeed.

I spent hours trying to fix it.
Here is what I did:

- Go to file .classpath at the project level and open in notepad and you must add the 3rd line here:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <classpath>
      <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
      <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
      <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
      <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
  </classpath>
  ```
- Also make sure that default.properties has these two lines (target android-4 is 1.6):

  ```
   target=android-4
   android.library=false
  ```

Comment: This will show my ignorance - I don't see a file .classpath  Where is it?

Comment: In eclipse -> Right-click on the project, click on properties, lookup the location.

Comment: I see no .classpath or any xml files.  When I click the android label, a message pops up saying "the currently display page contains invalid values".   Opening the Build Path show some folders but no class items...

Comment: You will see these in the windows explorer and not in the project itself since eclipse hides them. You have to edit them outside project.

Comment: Thanks for hanging in with.  I don't see it.  I looked at the folders and files but see nothing in the way of classes except my main java file and no xml files except the manifest.  (FYI, not that it should matter, but I'm using a mac). The following is from the java class: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
 Activity cannot be resolved to a type
 Override cannot be resolved to a type
 Bundle cannot be resolved to a type
 R cannot be resolved

Comment: Oh, one more thing - I see there is not default properties file in the project the the other projects have...

Comment: @headscratch If you're using a mac, try opening the file in Finder and pressing Command-h. This is because files starting with a period are treated as hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED after much time... and reading all the dev site info about the new SDK.

Basically, need to update everything android and ensure the new Proguard tool is installed.  All new apps created in the new SDK require it.  Also, needed to change the Path settings to the tools as the syntax changed... read about this stuff before you upgrade...

After doing this all went well and is working (fingers are crossed!)

Comment: Can you please post some links?

Comment: Can you outline what you did?